# Is making predictions kufr?

Tags: kufr, ilm-al-ghaib

It is shirk to claim knowledge of the unseen. So if I say that a person will become a bad writer when he grows up or will do bad in his exam am I claiming to know the unseen future?

If it isn't shirk to make predictions of the future by evidences and through studying the Laws of Allah (may he be exalted and praised) what of baseless predictions or false predictions people make for personal benefit?

Answer (score 3):

Depends, there is a difference between saying you **claim knowledge** of the unseen (for example this person will die tomorrow at noon) or **predicting a possibility** which may occur in the future based on facts and info available to you (for example based on the direction the tornado is heading it is estimated that it will cause 2 million in damage expenditure!).

I would say to **predict a POSSIBILITY** of something which may occur in the future based on facts is not haram.

But if you claim that it will definitely happen then you are claiming to have knowledge of the Ghaib

> “Say: “None in the heavens and the earth knows the Ghaib (Unseen)
>   except Allaah, nor can they perceive when they shall be resurrected”
>   [al-Naml 27:65]
>
> “And with Him are the keys of the Ghayb (all that is hidden), none
>   knows them but He. And He knows whatever there is in the land and in
>   the sea; not a leaf falls, but He knows it. There is not a grain in
>   the darkness of the earth nor anything fresh or dry, but is written in
>   a Clear Record”
>   [al-An’aam 6:59]

There are of course certain things which we can’t predict at all, such as judgement day, the anti-christ, gog and moug, death!

Comment: what is someone has no visible signs? For example, a father doesn't know what will happen to his son but in an attempt to discourage him he says that if his son studies engineering he will become a bad engineer.

Comment: @Nadim My advice from personal experience DON'T EVER DO THAT, one thing that parents don't often understand is that there is a point when they should stop commanding their kids and advice them instead, they should bear the consequences for their own decisions not the parents, the parents are not always there for their kids, therefore by making them commit to their own choices they can learn to survive on their own!

Comment: Actually, I'm writing a script where the father does this to his son.

Comment: So are baseless predictions considered shirk?

Comment: @Nadim i would say ignorance but allah knows best

Comment: I would suggest looking into the definition of shirk

Comment: To put it simply setting up partners with Allah is shirk.

Answer (score 0):

that's depend on the use of your predictions ..
so if i give for example a prediction , that judgement day is in 2022

then you will be asked by god upon this that you misled other innocent people.

if for example you gave upon study and testing researching on a degree of scientific methods that the price of gold will rise in the next 2 weeks 
an assumption ,, 
and others who are following you accepted that it may deter , based upon your agreement with them .. then its okay  , no haram here .

but its haram if you cheated on them in any way that you have full confidence and knowledge of predicting gold prices then you caused a loss to them , this way you deceived them or lied on them and its prohibited .

but anything which belong to religion then you should avoid prediction in it .

Comment: This answer will benefit from references. Try adding some.